How to change the kernel image in ubuntu 22.04?
I'm currently using ubuntu 22.04 LTS version, when I ran the "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade command" latest kernel has been downloaded but I don't know how to switch to the new kernel. Please guide me with the process.
Here is the screenshot of the boot folder

Changing kernels requires a reboot.
Try this first: On a normal, properly functioning Ubuntu system, simply rebooting will automatically load the new kernel.
If you unexpectedly reboot into the older kernel, then reboot again selecting the new kernel at GRUB.

How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?

Folks who still cannot reach the new kernel have systems that are either not-normal (self-inflicted) or not-properly-functioning (requires troubleshooting). They should open a new question detailing their unusual problem.

Thanks for helping I'll try it
